# Generalized inverse of a matrix on new columns

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, generalized-inverse

Assume that there exists a matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}(m\neq n)$ whose generalized inverse matrix is $X$, and $X$ satifies the formula:
$$
A=AXA\\
(AX)^T=AX
$$
How to calculate the generalized inverse matrix $Y$ of $B=\left[ A,a \right] \left(a\in R^{m\times t},m\neq n\right)$,which also satifies the formula:
$$
B=BYB\\
(BY)^T=BY
$$

Comment: What is $[A,a]$? I'd expect it to be $Aa-aA$ but the dimensions don't match.

Comment: You can compute $Y$ in the same way as you would compute $X$. Depending on the properties of the matrices $A$ and $B$, you may have a relationship between $X$ and $Y$. For instance, if the $A$ and $B$ are full row rank.